# What version of node and npm does Laravel 7 require?

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack

Where can I see what version of node and npm Laravel 7 require?

Nothing in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#installation

I got these versions installed, but getting errors when i run "npm run development"

```
npm -v
6.14.5

node -v
v6.17.0
```

Have been reading that old version of npm and node, might cause the reason. Have also been reading that the location of cross-env have been changed, but not sure what that means or where to change it :/

Error:

```
ec2-user:~/environment (master) $ npm run development

> @ development /home/ec2-user/environment
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:151
  async remove(item) {
        ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:186:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:98:17)
    at Module._compile (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at implementation (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Sass.js:55:27)
    at implementation (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:130:61)
    at global.tap (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:10:5)
    at Sass.loaderOptions (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:128:9)
    at extractPlugin (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:87:39)
    at global.tap (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:10:5)
    at details.forEach (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:27:13)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Sass.webpackRules (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Preprocessor.js:22:22)
    at ComponentFactory.applyRules (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:155:23)
    at Mix.listen.rules (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:66:48)
    at events.(anonymous function).forEach.handler (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:47)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Dispatcher.fire (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:28)
    at Mix.dispatch (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:118:25)
    at WebpackConfig.buildRules (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:90:13)
    at WebpackConfig.build (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:23:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:29:38)
    at Module._compile (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/.npm/_logs/2020-05-27T15_52_27_039Z-debug.log
```

Have tried to delete node_modules folder and then running "npm install", but still getting error.
Think i'm already running latest version of npm and node.

Answer (score 3):

Seems I fixed it.

This is what i did:

```
npm cache clean --force

rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

npm install
```

I then got this other error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
```

This worked:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev sass-loader
npm install --save-dev sass-loader@7.1.0
```

Can now run "npm run development" with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel version 7.30
Node js version 14.8 working for me.

```
npm install --save-dev
```